# Flutter: Argument passed becomes null on the receivers end

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a grocery store style app on flutter. I was first trying to get the very basic app to set up without implementing any UI changes when I ran into the following problem. When using

> Navigator.push

from one page to the second I am getting the error:

```
The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length
```

I have no idea why the following issue occurs because on printing the passed arguments on the first page give the true value whereas printing them on the receiver class gives null.
The first page of my code is the following:

```
// @dart=2.9
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'BillPage.dart';
import 'ItemData.dart';
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: FormPage(),
    );
  }
}

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FormPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => FormPageState();
}

class FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  List<ItemData> details;

  @override
  void initState() {
    details = [
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Onion Sambar',
        itemPrice: 81.5,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Pumpkin Disco',
        itemPrice: 49.5,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Chow Chow',
        itemPrice: 42,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Karela',
        itemPrice: 29,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Cauliflower',
        itemPrice: 35,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Raw Banana',
        itemPrice: 32,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Arvi - Colacasia',
        itemPrice: 33.5,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Sponge Gourd',
        itemPrice: 40,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Ridge Gourd',
        itemPrice: 49,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Fresh Brinjal',
        itemPrice: 34.5,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Raw Papaya',
        itemPrice: 27,
      ),
      ItemData(
        itemName: 'Drumstick',
        itemPrice: 24,
      ),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget _myCart() {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: details.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(details[index].itemName),
          // leading: details[index].image
          trailing: details[index].isAdded
              ? Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    if (details[index].counter > 0) {
                      details[index].counter--;
                    }
                  });
                },
                color: Colors.green,
              ),
              Text(details[index].counter.toString()),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                color: Colors.green,
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    details[index].counter++;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ],
          )
              : ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                details[index].isAdded = true;
              });
            },
            child: Text("Add"),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  // List<ItemData> _getBillItems() {
  //
  // }
  //
  // double _getAmt() {
  //   double amt = 0;
  //   for(ItemData item in details) {
  //     if(item.counter > 0) {
  //       amt += (item.itemPrice * item.counter);
  //     }
  //   }
  //   return amt;
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<ItemData> billList = [];
    double amt = 0;
    for(ItemData item in details) {
      if(item.counter > 0) {
        billList.add(item);
        amt += (item.itemPrice * item.counter);
      }
    }
    // return billList;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Vegetables'),
        ),
        body: _myCart(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Text(
          'Order'
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BillPage(
                items: billList,
                finalAmount: amt,
              )
              ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the second page as following:

```
// @dart=2.9
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'ItemData.dart';

class BillPage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<ItemData> items;
  double finalAmount;
  BillPage({Key key, List<ItemData> items, double finalAmount}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    // print('$items $finalAmount');

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Column (
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              itemCount: items.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                      items[index].itemName
                  ),
                  trailing: Text(
                      '${items[index].itemPrice} * ${items[index].counter}'
                  ),
                );
              }
              ),
          Text(
              'Total : $finalAmount'
          )
        ],
      )
    );
  }
}
```

The ItemData class is as follows:

```
// @dart=2.9
class ItemData {
  final String itemName;
  final double itemPrice;
  // final File image;
  int counter = 0;
  bool isAdded = false;
  ItemData({this.itemName, this.itemPrice/*, this.image */});
}
```

Any advice on how to fix the same would be helpful thank you.

Comment: I have not found the problems in your code yet, but you should try to pass arguments on pushing like Flutter document https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `BillPage` class, specially in the constructor:

```dart
class BillPage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<ItemData> items;
  double finalAmount;

  BillPage({Key key, List<ItemData> items, double finalAmount}) : super(key: key);

  // ...
}
```

Here, you have a parameter `items` in your constructor, which is being ignored, and a property `items`, which is always null since you're not modifying it anywhere (thus the receiver being null). To fix that, just do:

```dart
class BillPage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<ItemData> items;
  double finalAmount;

  BillPage({Key key, this.items, this.finalAmount}) : super(key: key);

  // ...
}
```

Now, the argument `items` passed in the constructor will be assigned to the `items` property.

Answer (score 0):

As Enzo suggested that should fix the issue as explains the Null issue.
I suggest also turning the object into "canonicalized" instance.  which will improve the performance.

```
class BillPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ItemData> items;
  final double finalAmount;

  const BillPage({Key key, this.items, this.finalAmount}) : super(key: key);

  // ...
}
```